# How to remove elements by their attributes using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xslt

I hope I'm not wasting anyone's time by reproducing a question. I am having difficulty relating my issue with the existing answers.

I am dealing with an xml file containing information relating to films.

I am attempting to use xslt to produce an html file with a button that will eliminate tuples from the table on press. This is a building block that I will then use to construct a more complex web site once I have understood this problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("button".click(function() {
            $("ryear[!='1997']").hide();
        });
</script>
<button>Click me to eliminate non-1997 films</button>

</head> 
<body>
<h2>A Table of Remade Movies</h2>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Original Title</th>
            <th>Original Year</th>
            <th>Fraction</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="remakes/remake">
        <tr>
            <td><rtitle><xsl:value-of select="rtitle"/></rtitle></td>
            <td><ryear><xsl:value-of select="ryear"/></ryear></td>
            <td><stitle><xsl:value-of select="stitle"/></stitle></td>
            <td><syear><xsl:value-of select="syear"/></syear></td>
            <td><fraction><xsl:value-of select="fraction"/></fraction></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Could someone point me in the direction of correcting this code? This solution will allow me to move on to the rest of my problems!

Thanks.

Comment: [**CSS Selectors**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and how to use them!

Comment: Can you say [**in english**] what are you trying to remove!

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. `$("button".click(function() {` and no closing `})`

Comment: Hi ibrahim, at the moment I'm trying to remove ryear elements which do not have the attribute '1997'. I'm hoping that understanding how to do this will enable me to build this up to a more complex solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Could you clarify please? Is `1997` the attribute's value or attribute's name? If it's the attribute's value then what is the attribute's name?

Comment: Sorry, 1997 is the attribute value. The attribute name is ryear.

Comment: `$('[ryear]:not([ryear="1997"])').remove();` Select all elements that have the attribute `ryear`, exclude those who have it equal to `"1997"` and remove the others. (because there is no **attribute-not-equal** selector)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a conversation with the original poster, we came up with a better way of getting the same functionality:

```js
function loadData(rocol) {
 var data = [];
 $(rocol).find('remake').each(function(){
    data.push([
    $(this).find("rtitle").text(),
    $(this).find("ryear").text(),
    $(this).find("fraction").text(),
    $(this).find("stitle").text(),
    $(this).find("syear").text()
    ])
   });
   return data; 
}

$.get("http://neil.computer/stack/movie.xml", function (data) {
 $('#example').dataTable( {
  data : loadData(data)
 } );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" /><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.13/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<table id="example">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Movie Title</th>
   <th>rYear</th>
   <th>Fraction</th>
   <th>sTitle</th>
   <th>sYear</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, this is a small sample of the XML that I'm using:

Comment: <remake>
  <rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
  <ryear>1938</ryear>
  <fraction>0.5</fraction>
  <stitle>Pygmalion</stitle>
  <syear>1937</syear>
 </remake>
 <remake>
  <rtitle>Pygmalion</rtitle>
  <ryear>1938</ryear>
  <fraction>0.2</fraction>
  <stitle>Twentieth Century</stitle>
  <syear>1934</syear>
 </remake>

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help with this. I can see that your solution works within the 'run code snippet', but when I apply it through my xslt processor, the html code that I get does not function. Perhaps I am missing some step that is causing this problem. Thanks again for your help as I'm very new at this.

Comment: Just send me the whole file on pastebin.

Comment: Do you want the xml file? I'm trying to put it up on pastebin but the website keeps freezing my browser!

Comment: So, you want me to just add my code directly into the xml file itself?

Comment: Can you let me know what is preventing the code from changing the .html displayed? If you update the hastebin that's fine.

Comment: at the moment I'm using xsltproc to transform xml file with xsl file into html, then using firefox to display the result. I think that my issue is due to this process, rather than an issue with the solutions that have been offered here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138421/discussion-between-grainman-and-nfn-neil).

Answer (score 1):

This code will work for you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
 <head>
<script src="jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("ryear").not(':contains(1997)').parents('tr').hide();
            });
        });
</script>
<button>Click me to eliminate non-1997 films</button>

</head> 
<body>
<h2>A Table of Remade Movies</h2>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Year</th>
            <th>Original Title</th>
            <th>Original Year</th>
            <th>Fraction</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="remakes/remake">
        <tr>
            <td><rtitle><xsl:value-of select="rtitle"/></rtitle></td>
            <td><ryear><xsl:value-of select="ryear"/></ryear></td>
            <td><stitle><xsl:value-of select="stitle"/></stitle></td>
            <td><syear><xsl:value-of select="syear"/></syear></td>
            <td><fraction><xsl:value-of select="fraction"/></fraction></td>
        </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi, at the moment, I can't make this work. My process now is: process the code above with your edits to an .xsl file. then use xsltproc to process the .xml file with it into an .html file. Then open the .html file with firefox to see the result. Is there something that I am doing wrong with this system?

Comment: Have you updated your xsl file as above code? You can also check the script $("ryear").not(':contains(1997)').parents('tr').hide(); on you browser's console

Comment: This is the working URL http://vindhyatest.comule.com/XMLFile.xml. Processing the same way you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").on('click', function(){ //.on is usable even if the element is added after your javascript is already be read
        $(this + '[ryear!="1997"]').hide(); //hide the ryear different then 1997
        //$(this + '[ryear!="1997"]').remove(); // use .remove if you want to remove from your html
    });
});
```